# data is empty even after saving a copy of it in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

```
var cacheData = JSON.stringify(data);

this.getTwitterSearch(data, options);

cache.setex(query, cfg.cache.news.twitter, cacheData, function(){
    c.log('set cache', query, cacheData);
});
```

If I comment out `this.getTwitterSearch` everything works fine. How can this be? I don't see how its possible that the function is making `cacheData` empty.

Here is `this.getTwitterSearch`:

```
News.prototype.getTwitterSearch = function getTwitterSearch(data, options){
    var statuses = data.statuses
        , items = [];

    c.log('statuses', statuses);

    _.each(statuses, function(d){
        var item = this.getTwitterItem(query, d);

        if ( item ) {
            items.push(item);
        }
    }.bind(this));

    //recent items since last poll
    if ( options.since_id ) {
        if ( items.length ) {
            this.sock.emit('twitter:new', { items: items });
        }
    } else {
        //initial payload
        c.log('twitter:items', items.length);
        if ( items.length ) {
            this.sock.emit('twitter:items', { items: items });
        }
    }

    c.log('items', items.length);

    //TODO set cache items

    //save the last id to use when fetching new items on next poll.
    this.lastId = items.length && items[0].id || this.lastId;
};
```

Comment: You sure there is no JS error caused by the call to `getTwitterSearch` ?

Comment: actually there was a subtle error causing the problem. it was just misleading that it was an error.

Comment: yes i added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error in `this.getTwitterItem(query, d);` it need the `query` parameter to be passed to it. Otherwise the error was being thrown to the `twit.search` callback and I was reading it as data, not an error.